# TailwindCSS ver3.3.3 not recognizing percentage customized widths

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I have this width customization for tailwind ver3.3.3 and it is not recognizing the value `4/48`

my widths config:

```
      width: {
        '12/25': '48%',
        '1/24': '4.166666%',
        '2/24': '8.333333%',
        '3/24': '12.5%',
        '4/24': '16.666666%',
        '5/24': '20.833333%',
        '6/24': '25%',
        '7/24': '29.166666%',
        '8/24': '33.333333%',
        '9/24': '37.5%',
        '10/24': '41.666666%',
        '11/24': '45.833333%',
        '12/24': '50%',
        '13/24': '54.166666%',
        '14/24': '58.333333%',
        '15/24': '62.5%',
        '16/24': '66.666666%',
        '17/24': '70.833333%',
        '18/24': '75%',
        '19/24': '79.166666%',
        '20/24': '83.333333%',
        '21/24': '87.5%',
        '22/24': '91.666666%',
        '23/24': '95.833333%',
        '24/24': '100%',
        '1/48': '2.083333%',
        '2/48': '4.166667%',
        '3/48': '6.25%',
        '4/48': '8.333333%',
        '5/48': '10.416667%',
        '6/48': '12.5%',
        '7/48': '14.583333%',
        '8/48': '16.666667%',
        '9/48': '18.75%',
        '10/48': '20.833333%',
        '11/48': '22.916667%',
        '12/48': '25%',
        '13/48': '27.083333%',
        '14/48': '29.166667%',
        '15/48': '31.25%',
        '16/48': '33.333333%',
        '17/48': '35.416667%',
        '18/48': '37.5%',
        '19/48': '39.583333%',
        '20/48': '41.666667%',
        '21/48': '43.75%',
        '22/48': '45.833333%',
        '23/48': '47.916667%',
        '24/48': '50%',
        '25/48': '52.083333%',
        '26/48': '54.166667%',
        '27/48': '56.25%',
        '28/48': '58.333333%',
        '29/48': '60.416667%',
        '30/48': '62.5%',
        '31/48': '64.583333%',
        '32/48': '66.666667%',
        '33/48': '68.75%',
        '34/48': '70.833333%',
        '35/48': '72.916667%',
        '36/48': '75%',
        '37/48': '77.083333%',
        '38/48': '79.166667%',
        '39/48': '81.25%',
        '40/48': '83.333333%',
        '41/48': '85.416667%',
        '42/48': '87.5%',
        '43/48': '89.583333%',
        '44/48': '91.666667%',
        '45/48': '93.75%',
        '46/48': '95.833333%',
        '47/48': '97.916667%',
        '48/48': '100%',
        88: '22rem',
        140: '35rem',
      },
```

What could be the problem? I had this same config with Tailwind ver2.2.16 and was working without troubles.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider checking: the object is declared at `theme.width` or `theme.extend.width` in `tailwind.config.js` (or a correct equivalent), you are not using string concatenation/interpolation to build the class name in source code and that the source code that uses the `width-*` class(es) are covered by the Tailwind `content` file globs.

Comment: No, I'm not using interpolation with JavaScript, I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Consider checking you are not using string concatenation/interpolation to build the class name in source code regardless of the language used. Also consider checking the other points too.

Comment: @Wongjn you were right the problem was replacing the `w-*`, I had to put the full class without replacing like `w-4/48`. Thank you!